# Global page breaking as in TeXmacs

Tags: typography, texmacs

One of the most distinctive features of TeX is that the line breaking algorithm is "global", as achieved by minimising a penalty over the entire paragraph.  This is one of the most important features of TeX which makes its typesetting quality so high with respect to other software.

In TeXmacs, they implemented a similar global algorithm for page breaking.  Indeed, in "plain" LaTeX, page breaks often occur at weird places.  In TeXmacs, this tends to occur less often.  Are there any variants of TeX or LaTeX that implement a global algorithm for page breaking?  Is this doable?

Taking into account some of the comments, I make my question a bit more precise.  Is there a LaTeX style package that enables global page breaking and that comes with style parameters in order to control some of the decisions about page breaks?

Comment: this question would be much better without unsubstantiated statements. define `weird`  preferably with a complete test example document. As it is with your personal biases expressed as facts it is not really possible to give any objective answer.

Comment: Well, you understand that such documents are typically quite long.  Just to mention a few instances of "weird": pages that start with a formula, pages that end with a section title, pages that start with the last line of a section, etc.'

Comment: latex never makes a page break after a section title, (unless you have made definitions that break the system) don't just throw in random unsubstansiated things that you say the system does wrong and some other system does better. Show an example document and someone will no doubt show you how to improve the tex markup and get a better result.

Comment: Well maybe I misremembered this particular item (although there definitely exist broken style files indeed).  But my point is that I am not interested in knowing how to improve my LaTeX markup.  What I want is LaTeX to do things right automatically or at least be able to set some style variables to get something that is as good as possible.  So once again, is there a style package that I can use that enables global page breaking, yes (which one) or no?

Comment: @Gérard Maybe it is not the best strategy to base your question on unfounded claims about "weird page breaking"? You have to torture latex a lot to get such an output you describe. I'm sure there are also users who manage to produce bad results in texmacs, that does not mean texmacs itself is bad, does it?

Comment: That's like saying: look, there is at least one person who produced at least one formula in texmacs with incorrect spacing around the decimal separator and wrong font for the units https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0mds.png - let's conclude that all texmacs must be bad

Answer (score 5):

There are several mechanisms for doing global page breaking in tex, they haven't been used much in practice, as in earlier times the memory available made this difficult, and now memory is available there are only limited classes of document where there is sufficient flexibility in page breaking to make a difference but for example this paper available from the latex project website describes a modern technique making use of the extra facilities in luatex.

https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2018-01-FMi-CI-Journal-28454894_as_submitted.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the interesting pointer.  Not very professional of the author of this paper though that TeXmacs is not mentioned; many of the ideas were implemented there right from the start around 2000 (I believe; to be checked).

Comment: Why are there "only limited classes of document where there is sufficient flexibility in page breaking to make a difference"?  I find this feature to be highly useful, although it can be distracting when editing files in a wysiwyg manner in "page mode".

Comment: why should texmacs be mentioned in a paper discussing global page breaking in luatex? why not lout or nrioff or any other system you care to mention????

Comment: Why?: because every paragraph has word spaces so benefits from white space adjustment to justify lines, but in document classes that have mostly text the line spacing is fixed so there is no flexibility or local or global optimisation, you just need to break at the end of the page. so the situation is not at all the same.  magazine layouts with lots of floating figures and lots of headings and adjustable space are a different matter, but not usually the kind of document set with tex.

Comment: texmacs is far from the first to consider that, here's a 2000 paper on global page breaking with tex, and I suspect I could find some from the 1980s if I searched harder http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb21-3/tb68fine.pdf,

Comment: The paper has the format and appearance of a scientific paper.  In that case, it should meet scientific citation standards and be aware whether similar ideas were already used before.  In this case, they were implemented more than 20 years ago, so the proposed technique is not "modern" at all, as you misleadingly state.

Comment: Your comments are not particulary reasonable, the concept of global optimisation of page breaking is as old as typography so not modern at all, that paper is discussing techniques that have relatively recently become available using luatex. The fact that some other system may or may not have some version of global optimisation of page breaks isn't relevant at all. @Gérard

Comment: OK, please search harder then.  I am also interested in actual implementations.  What should I do _concretely speaking_ to use global page breaking in LaTeX?

Comment: We are talking about automatic global page breaking and actual implementations, not about conceptual speculations.

Comment: @Gérard  Plass's thesis (under supervision of Prof. Knuth) on a page breaking version of tex's line breaker, 1981 https://tug.org/docs/plass/plass-thesis.pdf

Comment: Reply to "Why?".  I don't agree.  Typical papers with mathematical formulas, sections, and theorems (for other types of papers, most people use Word) have lots of opportunities for vertical adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Plass's thesis.  That indeed seems to be a more serious scientific study of the problem.  But my original question remains unanswered: how can we _concretely_ use this from within LaTeX?

Comment: sorry you don't find Frank serious, he has lead the team maintening latex for the last 30 years, That is the state of the art, you are free to have other opinions but opinion based questions are explicitly discouraged on this network.

Comment: For a scientific article, it makes sense do a bit more research on existing implementations.  If Frank is not taking TeXmacs seriously, then that is not very nice and not very professional if he decides to write a scientific paper on such a topic.  Which does not mean that I disrespect his work on LaTeX, but I don't see what is track record has to do with my question.  By the way, the whole thing came up in the discussion (that you heated up), not at all in my question.

Comment: @Gérard you seem to have a thing for texmacs this week but I can not see why anyone should expect texmacs (or 3b2 or lout or patoline or..) to be mentioned in a paper describing new features in luatex.  It's not a matter of taking it seriously or not seriously, it simply isn't relevant to the subject at hand.

Comment: It is relevant for a paper on "global page breaking", I guess.  How many actually usable implementations are there?  And again, _how_ to use this in LaTeX, _concretely_ speaking?  The whole discussion has become a tangent, and my actual question remains unanswered!

Comment: Back to the topic.  You say "There are several mechanisms for doing global page breaking in tex".  That is not very precise.  Could you be more specific?  Is there some style package that we can use to make this happen?

Comment: Yes David, as I already stated during the discussion "where to ask questions about TeXmacs", I indeed have "a thing for TeXmacs this week".  But it seems that you have something personal against me (or maybe against TeXmacs?), because I tend to get downvoted everywhere as soon as you appear.  Not a very friendly welcome on this network.

Comment: @Gérard huh? why do you write such nonsense? As you can see in my profile I don't downvote. Of all the thousands of people on this site, I'm the one who's tried to answer your questions constructively even though they are ill formed and only marginally on topic. But it seems that you are not interested in asking questions or having answers, just want to use the Q&A format to promote texmacs. I don't downvote but I did vote to clse as "opinion based" which is a standard close reason on the platform